# Mysql: Select last occurence of every ID

Tags: mysql

I have multiple occurrences of a Client-ID called "IDKLIENT". I want to select the last occurrence of IDKLIENT for each ID, like

```
1|x  2|x
1|y  2|y
1|z  2|z
```

would be:

```
1|z
2|z
```

I used this code:

```
select a.*
      from  test a inner join 
      (select Name_Kl, max(IDKLIENT) as maxid from test group by IDKLIENT) as b on a.IDKLIENT = b.maxid
```

This way, I only get the same output as with

`select a.*`

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The table also has timestamps. So I would be content, if for each ID the max(timestamp) is selected.

Comment: Define 'last'. Rows in an RDBMS table have no order

Comment: Ok, then 'last` could be max(timestamp) of the ID.

Comment: Timestamp of what? I only see a number and a character in your table.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the expected output, I believe you are looking to group by id to find the alphabetically greatest value for idklient. You can sort alphabetically by idklient using `max` if that is what you need:

```
select id, max(idklient) from test group by id;
```

If instead, you want it sorted by the insert order, I would suggest having an AUTO_INCREMENT field which you can then use to do the grouping. This might work better than inserting a timestamp

In response to your edit:

```
select id, max(timestamp) from test group by id;
```

> This is a classic example for the [group-by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html) statement

Answer (score 0):

I think group by has been changed.

Try this way

```
select a.*
from  test a
    inner join 
        (select Name_Kl, max(IDKLIENT) as maxid 
         from test 
         group by Name_Kl
        ) as b 
          on a.IDKLIENT = b.maxid
```